Cannot load a geodataframe (from a shapefile) into PostgreSQL (as table) via SQLAlchemy
I would like to publish a shapefile from a directory to GeoServer by using the Python library geoserver-rest.
I understand that in order to do so, I need also to load the shapefile as geodataframe (table) into my database (by using PostGIS extension), because geoserver-rest needs shapefile data from a table in order to publish it on GeoServer. I am doing the loading into the database via SQLAlchemy.
The database is correctly configured: the following command allows me to access the database
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres

PostgreSQL version is 14.12, PostGIS is installed.
SELECT extname FROM pg_extension where extname='postgis';

 extname 
---------
 postgis

Schema data has been created
create schema data;

GeoServer is up and running.
The path of my shapefile is stored in req_shp:
/home/.../django/geoApp/media/shp/20240713_234254/C_Jamoat/jamoat-db.shp

Here below is my script.
The problem is that I cannot get the shapefile loaded into the database, and I don't understand why. I am getting no logs from sqlalchemy.
This is how my credentials are evaluated:
geoapp_db_params
{'user': 'postgres', 'password': 'password', 'host': 'localhost', 'port': '5432', 'dbname': 'postgres'}

GEOSERVER_CREDENTIALS: 
{'user': 'admin', 'password': 'geoserver'}

conn_str: 
postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres

Here is my script:
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# define variables
#-------------------

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password', 
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

geoapp_db_params = {
        'user':     DATABASES['default']['USER'],
        'password': DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'],
        'host':     DATABASES['default']['HOST'],
        'port':     DATABASES['default']['PORT'],
        'dbname':   DATABASES['default']['NAME'],    
}

conn_str = 'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'.format( **geoapp_db_params )

GEOSERVER_CREDENTIALS = {
    'user': 'admin',
    'password': 'geoserver'
}

geo = Geoserver(
            'http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver', 
            username=GEOSERVER_CREDENTIALS['user'], 
            password=GEOSERVER_CREDENTIALS['password']
            )

# workspace name
wksp_name = 'geoapp'

# store name
ste_name = 'geoApp'

# schema name
schm_name = 'data'

# style name
sty_name = 'geoApp_shp_style' 

instance_name = "region1"

# load shapefile into the database
#----------------------------------

# create a  geodataframe
gdf = gpd.read_file(req_shp)  

engine = create_engine(conn_str)

# load geodataframe into a postgres table
gdf.to_postgis(
    con=engine,
    schema=schm_name,
    name=instance_name,
    if_exists="replace"
)

print("Instance {} was sent to_postgis!".format(instance_name))

# create workspace
#----------------------------------

if not geo.get_workspace(wksp_name):
    print("create workspace '{}'".format(wksp_name))
    geo.create_workspace(wksp_name)


# print("getting workspace:", geo.get_workspace(wksp_name))
   
   
# create and publish featurestore
#----------------------------------

geo.create_featurestore(workspace=wksp_name, 
                        store_name=ste_name, 
                        schema=schm_name,

                        db=geoapp_db_params['dbname'], 
                        host=geoapp_db_params['host'], 
                        pg_user=geoapp_db_params['user'], 
                        pg_password=geoapp_db_params['password']
                        )

print("shp:\n\tcreated featurestore: {}".format(ste_name))

# print(wksp_name, ste_name, schm_name, geoapp_db_params['dbname'],geoapp_db_params['host'],geoapp_db_params['user'], geoapp_db_params['password'])


geo.publish_featurestore(workspace=wksp_name, 
                        store_name=ste_name, 
                        pg_table=instance_name)

print("shp:\n\tpublished featurestore: {}\n\tpg_table: {}".format(ste_name, instance_name))


# create and publish style
#----------------------------------

geo.create_outline_featurestyle(sty_name, 
                                workspace=wksp_name)
# the first argument is the output style name

print("shp:\n\tcreated outline featurestyle {}".format(sty_name))


geo.publish_style(
    layer_name=instance_name, 
    style_name=sty_name, 
    workspace=wksp_name)

print("shp:\n\tpublished style {} for shp layer {}".format(sty_name, instance_name))


Don't ever use the postgres user to load data into the database. Doing so can break your database instance in ways that can't be fixed.

As suggested by @Vince , I have created a new database with a new user ( owner of the database ), reinstalled postgis, recreated the schema data, configured the django app for it, run makemigrations, migrate, createsuperuser.
Now the .shp files added to the shp model are also loaded into the database (in the schema data) and also in geoserver-rest. I can see them in layer preview.
NOTE: it is better to avoid to pass to geoserver-rest or to sqlalchemy any element name (tables, layers, storagestore, featurstore) having any character other  than lowercase alphanumeric and underscore.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'geoappdb',
        'USER': 'geoapp_main',
        'PASSWORD': 'geomain',  # ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

